# Changing css on dropdown list click

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I am trying to change the CSS stylesheet on my website so that the background colors can be changed.
It worked with buttons but when i tried to put it in a dropdown list, it doesn't apply the css sheet switch.

Can anyone help me out?

```
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var style_cookie_name = "style";
  var style_cookie_duration = 30;



  function switch_style(css_title) {

      var i, link_tag;
      for (i = 0, link_tag = document.getElementsByTagName("link");
i < link_tag.length; i++) {
          if ((link_tag[i].rel.indexOf("stylesheet") != -1) &&
  link_tag[i].title) {
              link_tag[i].disabled = true;
              if (link_tag[i].title == css_title) {
                  link_tag[i].disabled = false;
              }
          }
          set_cookie(style_cookie_name, css_title,
  style_cookie_duration);
      }
  }
  function set_style_from_cookie() {
      var css_title = get_cookie(style_cookie_name);
      if (css_title.length) {
          switch_style(css_title);
      }
  }
  function set_cookie(cookie_name, cookie_value,
lifespan_in_days, valid_domain) {

      var domain_string = valid_domain ?
                   ("; domain=" + valid_domain) : '';
      document.cookie = cookie_name +
                   "=" + encodeURIComponent(cookie_value) +
                   "; max-age=" + 60 * 60 *
                   24 * lifespan_in_days +
                   "; path=/" + domain_string;
  }
  function get_cookie(cookie_name) {

      var cookie_string = document.cookie;
      if (cookie_string.length != 0) {
          var cookie_value = cookie_string.match(
                    '(^|;)[\s]*' +
                    cookie_name +
                    '=([^;]*)');
          return decodeURIComponent(cookie_value[2]);
      }
      return '';
  }
```

```
<select>
                <option value="submit" onclick="switch_style('Site');return false;" id="Site"/>Thema 1</option>
                <option value="submit" onclick="switch_style('Site2');return false;" id="Site2"/>Thema 2</option>

                </select>
```

Comment: Woops, i meant that it didn't give the result i wanted, instead when i click on one of the dropdown options it just stays the way it is.

Comment: I do not see where you link the dropdown box with the JavaScript code. It seems your code example is not complete?

Comment: I've changed the description, sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `option` tag does not accept the `onclick` event in a number of browsers:  http://webbugtrack.blogspot.ca/2007/11/bug-280-lack-of-events-for-options.html

An alternative would be to attach an `onchange` event to the `select`:

```js
function switch_style(theme) {
  alert(theme);
}
```

```html
<select onchange="switch_style(this.value)">
  <option value="Thema 1">Thema 1</option>
  <option value="Thema 2">Thema 2</option>
</select>
```